# How to call and display a PYQT UI script from another python script?

Tags: python, qt, subprocess, pyqt4

using subprocess.call im trying to call a PYQT popup ui class and pass a selection of arguments but im unable to find the correct why to do so

these are just two out of many iv tried

```
subprocess.call(['python','-c' 'from pop_up_package import ui_main; ui_main.ui_main', arg1, arg2])

subprocess.call(['python', '-c',"from pop_up_package import ui_main; ui_main.ui_main('%s','%s')"% (arg1, arg2)])
```

would anybody have any tips or point me in the direction i need to go

thanks

Comment: Why don't you just import the other script?

Answer (score 0):

Personally I wouldn't choose to do it this way. From what I can gather you are trying to call a PyQt class that resides in a separate file. Would it not be possible to have both of the UI classes in the same file. By doing that you could open up the separate window by using a connect statement for example, if the window is opened when a button is clicked. If you decide to do it this way then PyQt won't let you parse arguments through a connect but by putting "lambda:" at the start of the connect brackets you can place the function call as per usual.

If you could possibly include the code that runs as the new window is supposed to open as well as the code that is being called that might help people to answer your question more specifically.

I hope that helped but please do reply if you have any further questions.

Thanks,

BoshJailey

Comment: thanks for your reply, i was looking to create a standalone ui that can be accessed by multiplte applications with a simple call, i dont need to return anythin or capture any feedback, it is just solely to display information via the passed args